# FullCalendar mes e ano corrente

Tags: fullcalendar

Boa noite a todos, estou precisando saber se existe uma forma de pegar o mes e o ano corrente do `FullCalendar`, quando clicamos em avançar ou retroceder.

Não consegui descobrir qual é o evento que dispara quando clica nos botões de avançar e retroceder de datas.
A idéia e ter essas datas para fazer a pesquisa numa base de dados e trazer os eventos do mês que esta sendo exposto na tela do `Fullcalendar`, por exemplo outubro 2017.

Existiria uma outra forma de passar esses dados para a pesquisa na base de dados? Estou usando uma array com json para o `setFullCalendarEvents = function(){}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom dia a todos!
Quero compartilhar uma solução que acabei achando.
Eu estou usando um template que tem o fullcalendar, então pesquisando na documentação achei a seguinte solução:
Criei 3 botões: avançar, retroceder, HOJE .
A função que resgata a data apresentada é:

```
var moment = $('#full-calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
var dt = moment.format()
```

Temos as seguintes funções que fazem o papel de avançar, retroceder e hoje:

```
$('#full-calendar').fullCalendar('prev');

$('#full-calendar').fullCalendar('today');

$('#full-calendar').fullCalendar('next');
```

Fazem o calendario avançar, retroceder e ficar no dia de HOJE

Coloquei essas funções nos respectivos botões:

```
$(".prev_data").click(function(){ 
    $('#full-calendar').fullCalendar('prev');
     var moment = $('#full-calendar').fullCalendar('getDate');
     alert(moment.format());
});
```

Pronto, consegui resgatar a mês/ano que esta sendo exibido, quando avançamos ou retrocedemos os meses no calendario.
Abraço a todos